# How to not apply initState value on React Hook when onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

How to make react hook **NOT** return initial value at first time render?

Here is the sandbox to describe what my problem ( the `dummyFile` contain my project code)
https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-dijkstra-opidm?file=/src/index.js

Scenario : I want to get user input when click login button and compare them to a json file (in sandbox is `1234` is data from json) to check user and password they input, using Formik so login data save in json data format (like `{'username':abc@gmail.com,"password":1234}`), so i have only way(or fast and easy to understand) is to use 2 hook to store username and password respectively. But problem is, when i press login button, it show initial state of hook, in this sandbox is "init State", so data comparison always false `( console.log(username==="1234")` in this sandbox, so how can i get data and compare them correctly?

They alway show changed data **after** click

**Here is error**

[image]

**Here is error in  my project**

As you can see, it log nothing (the initial state because i set `useState("")`)

[image]

Here is a gif to describe more detail the error
[image]

Please help me, thank you a lot, i'm just started learn react and react-native, so i'm very appreciate your help

Comment: Please help :((

Comment: You're seeing the initial value the first time becuase `setUsername` is sort of an asynchronous operation, so the username is not changed immediately. In order to  have some action happen when the username changes, you can use a  `useEffect` that depends on `username`.

Comment: thank for your answer, but can you give me example of this? how can i make useEffect depend on `username`? And i notice, that `username` **not** change until second click( which not good because click action is login action), and how can i apply that for login action, i mean if i `username` changed, then button must be clicked? Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use the value directly?

```
<Formik
  validateOnMount
  validationSchema={loginValidationSchema}
  initialValues={{email: '', password: ''}}
  onSubmit={value => {
    getUsername(value.email)
    getPassword(value.password)
    console.log('User from local ' + value.email)
    console.log('User from Json ' + user.username) ///console log but return nothing
    SetTimer()
  }}
// () => navigation.navigate('Login')
>
```

The functions that set the state (in your case `getUsername`) is an async function, and the set value will not be available if not until the next render

Comment: Thank for your answer but I don't get it, i mean, if i use outside Formik function, how to get these value(the input value)

Comment: But i understand your idea, i will do it by that way, maybe i'm make thing more complex than it should

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `useEffect` that  performs the action, which depends on `username`.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("init state");

  /// How to make this value return '1233' when apply onCLick?
  useEffect(() =>{
    if(username !== "init state"){
      console.log(username);
    }
  }, [username])

  //always false, how to return true for first time
  console.log(username === "1234");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setUsername("1234");
        }}
      >
        Login
      </button>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but how can i  `console.log(username === "1234")` true for the first time ? I mean my goal is to compare username and some data correctly for the **first time** button clicked, how can i do that, i try make ` console.log(username === "1234");` in useEffect and it work but if i pass a function, it won't work

Comment: The code in the useEffect will log "1234" the first time the button is clicked.